# Light bottom panel without too many dependencies?

Tags: panel

When it comes to installing a dock there is Plank and Cairo, which one can install independently of the specific distro and desktop environment.

But what about a bottom panel?

What if instead of using [a dock like some do in Ubuntu Unity](http://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-f3fb6e22f392d5bb14ae27278ea6654d?convert_to_webp=true) one would trey to have a panel, like in Xfce, LXDE, Mate, Cinnamon etc -- what would be the most distro/DE independent, light on resources and not requiring too many dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [tint2](https://code.google.com/p/tint2/), [fbpanel](http://fbpanel.sourceforge.net/) (C and GTK+), [lxpanel](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lxde/files/LXPanel%20%28desktop%20panel%29/) (based on fbpanel).

There's also [pypanel](http://pypanel.sourceforge.net/) which is said to be a lightweight panel/taskbar and written in Python and C.

Even though tint2 was made for openbox and lxpanel was made for lxde, I believe they don't have many dependencies. Also keep in mind that you'll probably have to heavily customize this panels to look good (compared to cairo or plank, which look nice out-of-the-box).

Answer (score 0):

I have been on Linux 15+ years now.

I am currently exploring lxpanel vs tint2 for a week now on my laptop.

They both seem VERY light on resources.

First thing to note is tint2 does NOT offer an applications menu or start menu if you please.

tint3 is in development which brings me to my next point, tint2/3 is more or less a google development and is not very old.

After a week of searching there is a way to launch the openbox menu from a tint2 launcher icon using xdotool and keybindings, but this is the OPENBOX menu not a tint2 menu which you can just right click the background to get it.

Also have found out you can install openbox-menu and lxmenu-data (the program that auto fills the lxde menu with apps) and with a bit of configuration editing it will auto add programs to the openbox menu.

Other than trying to do something like setup a start menu, you can use the GUI to make it look good.  The GUI to me seemed overdone,there is something to be said about simplicity.

Tint2 after ALOT of config looks great and works well with almost no dependancies.

That Said..

lxpanel is plug and play and comes with lxmenu-data setup already..

To configure it you can literally right click and use the GUI...

The GUI is very simple and it is quick and easy to get things looking how you like.

lxpanel after a couple minutes can be fully up and working looking great.

lxpanel does have about 3 dependencies that install with it but it is very minimal.

lxpanel is VERY comparable to tint2 on resource usage.

One last note lxpanel is from LXDE which is currently a stalled development in favor of developing the very similar LXQt.  (GTK vs QT base)

The lxqt-panel is also lightweight and something I will be looking at next.

Hope this helps

Good Luck

New addition

vala-panel

Just started playing with this one but impressed quickly.

As easy as lxpanel to setup.

Looks fairly nice and easy GUI settings.

Apparently originally baised on lxpanel but has been re-written.

A few dependencies but still light weight.

I may keep this one.